# jQuery - how to jump to a specific slide when clicking a nav bullet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider made with jQuery which is working how I want it to. I have also added nav bullets, but how do I get them working so the user can jump to every slide?

Do I have to change the position of each slide everytime or is there a better, easier solution for it?

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/dRVmzx

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {



    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
  var bullets = [$(".bullets a:first-child"), $(".bullets a:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".bullets a:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".bullets a:last-child")];
  var sliderPos = 1;

  setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');

        });
    };

    function moveRight() {


        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            if(sliderPos == 0){bullets[3].removeClass("active-bullet");}
            if(sliderPos != 0){bullets[sliderPos - 1].removeClass("active-bullet")}
            bullets[sliderPos].addClass("active-bullet");


            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
            sliderPos++;
          if(sliderPos == 4){sliderPos = 0;}
        });
    };

});    


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 main-holder">
      <div id="slider">
        <ul>
          <li>SLIDE 1</li>
          <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
          <li>SLIDE 3</li>
          <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="bullets">
        <a href="" class="active-bullet">•</a>
        <a href="">•</a>
        <a href="">•</a>
        <a href="">•</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnails">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="text-holder">

      </div>
    </div>

  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);   

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

.bullets{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;

  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.bullets a{
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc;
}

.bullets a:hover{
  color: #E22C26!important;
}

.active-bullet {
  color: #E22C26!important;
}

.thumbnails{
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.text-holder{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: please just downloaded a solid slider from the internet, since your code isn't in par with minimum coding standards. regarding your question, the slides themselves should not be moved, but their container is moving, giving the illusion the slides are moving. this is done almost entirely by CSS, and the javascript amount needed is quite small.

Comment: Here's a slider i've made in the past [super awesome slider](https://github.com/yairEO/saSlider) try it

Comment: Is it possible to adjust your slider so I can have clickable thumbnails beside the main-slide? So they work like nav bullets

Comment: you can edit the source code to generate any pagination you would like (now it's using `<i></i>` as bullets)..This is a good idea to improve my slider to have configurable way to easily change the pagination elements.